# What form is "в гости"?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

So, *"Я в гостях"* seems to be prepositional plural of *гость*

*"Я иду в гости"* leaves me puzzled, though. According to conjugation tables, it is nominative plural, while *в* used to express direction requires accusative (which is *гостя* or *гостей* - *"Я иду в гостя/гостей"* just sounds silly).

What form are we dealing with here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two objections to people dismissing this "because it's an adverb":

1. Adverb or not, it started out as a noun and a preposition, and the case form still has to be explained somehow.
2. More importantly: you can say **в жёны** is also an adverb, and **в пионеры** too, but what about **(произведён) в полковники**? Or Pushkin's **мы все глядим в Наполеоны**? Are they really just that many ad hoc adverbs?

I'd say we're dealing with another "lesser case" — along with the locative-prepositional (**в снегу**) and partitive-genitive (**выпить чаю**). This one we may call [translative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translative_case)-accusative — which is indeed what it's described as (*превратительный падеж*) [here](http://ilyabirman.ru/meanwhile/all/cases/), though I don't know what the ultimate source of that list is.

It can of course be argued that the literal meaning of **в гости** isn't necessarily a change of status to one of a guest; more intuitively, we tend to think of this **гости** as a kind of abstract territorial notion (**в гостях** thus referring to a sort of guest-space), but I think this is a later shift of perception and the original usage, which accounts for the ending, was the same as with the other "translative" examples (which isn't contradicted by **в гостях**; compare **в денщиках у фельдкурата**).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I feel like it is the most convincing yet. 
I must say I get a little jolt of fear every time "lesser cases" are mentioned, though

Comment: @PashaSyrnikov Fear, why? Personally I feel that the whole idea of a "case" has a similar kind of blurry boundaries as "species" in biology. It seems likely that in inflecting (rather than agglutinative) languages, the very process that resulted in several paradigms with equivalent but non-identical grammatical endings was a gradual convergence from a primordial soup of grammatical accidents, so it's no surprise that some of those accidents still survive and new ones occasionally spring up.

Comment: I think, this strange acc. case which you call "translative-accusative" got its form (which coincides with nom.) from the Old Russian regular acc., from the times before the category of animate/inanimate developed. In those times the nom.pl. and acc.pl. forms coincided, and the category of animacy appeared specially to distinguish those cases in pl. But it looks like in some kinds of expressions animate nouns kept the relic acc.pl.=nom.pl. forms. I wouldn't call those forms a case, even a small one, since only the semantic class of animate nouns has them, it doesn't cover all the nouns.

Comment: Thank you for this analysis, it sounds quite convincing. However, speaking of the "abstract territorial notion" -- what about ***из варяг в греки***?

Comment: Why not territorial? "В шведы" in old texts? Here, шведы literally means the same as modern-days English name for that country, huh?

Comment: @bipll good point, but гости works the opposite way, doesn't it? it describes the goer, not the destination.

Comment: @AviGordon good point, but в гости does not mean going to a place inhabited by guests.

Comment: To me, it describes a state transition, that is something attached to the goer, who has inherent property of being in a state but the state itself can vary. And гости is the target state here, as you've noted before.

Comment: @NikolayErshov "fear" because my colleagues and I are trying to systematise as much of Russian grammar as possible, and these lesser cases create problems both for us and for learners. Primordial soup of grammatical accidents is fine and dandy if you have the stomach for it, while I fear indigestion

Comment: Another instance where animacy in the accusative case is ignored is the expression "выйти замуж" instead of the more obvious "выйти за мужа".

Comment: @DavidC I think it started out as `зá мужа`, and the semantically weak ending was eliminated by the time it was already an adverb – meaning that animacy wasn't ignored for as long as there *was* any animacy to ignore.

Comment: @NikolayErshov assumes that "в гости does not mean going to a place inhabited by guests". But maybe it does. Maybe "в гости" means "into a company of guests" and "в гостях" means "in a company of guests".

Comment: @DavidC I don't "assume" it, I argue it. `В`+animacy-ignoring plural accusative indicating a *role* of some sort: dozens of examples. (Actually any number of examples, since it's still productive.) Ditto, indicating the name of a territory formed by pluralising the term for its inhabitants: *exclusively* a limited number of obsolete toponyms (`из варяг в греки`). I get that it sounds like a cool idea, but your "maybe" is a "probably not".

Comment: @NikolayErshov I missed the fact that you had already mentioned and rejected the "abstract territorial notion" theory in your answer. Perhaps you could elaborate on your reasons for rejecting it in favor of the translative-accusative theory. Particularly, it is not clear to me how you explain "в гостях" and "в денщиках у фельдкурата", two examples which seem to support the metaphorical-space theory.

Comment: @DavidC Let's be clear now: *every* use of `в` is ultimately spatial, whether literally or metaphorically. The thing is, what you're suggesting with `в гостях` as "in a company of guests" would in fact be a non-metaphorical use of `в`. It's `гостях` that's the abstraction here, a synecdochal reference to a location. Like I said, it's how we tend to intuitively parse `в гостях` nowadays, but I maintain that originally, it was much more likely a truly metaphorical `в` like the one in `в денщиках` — referring to who you are (or "who you're being"), not where you are. Who has more than one valet?

Answer (score 1):

According to **Русский язык в задачах и ответах By Борис Норман** (p. 288 point 3.90)

[image: Русский язык в задачах и ответах By Борис Норман, p. 288 point 2.90]

"в гости" is "предложно-падёжная форма имени (???), that has almost become and adverb"

So it's not quite an adverb, and also includes the preposition

Comment: preposition **is** the part of adverb here

Comment: yes, the preposition indeed **is** part of the set phrase. that's why I wrote "...includes the preposition" and "в гости" in my answer.

furthermore, we have established that this phrase is not an adverb in the first place

Comment: So Boris Norman is asserting that we can answer the question "куда" using в + the prepositional case? That does not make sense. Saying that it has "almost turned into an adverb" does not clear things up.

Comment: I think my translation of "предложно-падёжная форма" is incorrect. Here is some sort of explanation https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/
It has nothing to do with prepositional case, and Boris Norman doesn't claim otherwise. Anyhow, Nikolay Ershov's answer here is the most helpful, let's not dwell on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a kind of 'fossilized' expression, that's why it doesn't seem to fit into the modern case system. #449 in Wade's 'A Comprehensive Russian Grammar' mentions that в is used with nouns in what looks like nom. pl., but is historically an accusative, in contexts of professions or other groups; sometimes it implies a change of state or status. A few similar expressions:

> ИГИЛ набирает детей в солдаты. --> ISIS is recruiting children to be soldiers.
>
> кандидат в солдаты --> a presidential candidate
>
> Каких женщин мужчины берут в жёны? --> What kind of women do men marry (lit., take to be a wife)?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that "в гости" is an adverb ("наречие"), so the real answer is the concept of case is just not applicable, since though this form is indeed derived from noun, it sort of solidified.

Just like we don't think of word "воля" when we use word "поневоле". Or, another example, "втиши".

**UPD:** Reacting on what @Nikolay Ershov is claiming. Indeed, one can just ask - OK, but why the original form was "в гости". Speaking of "lesser" cases, this could be a good candidate for traces [illative](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2) case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some nouns are used both as animate (Nom=Gen) and inanimate (Nom=Accus), depending on the context.

Like the "добавить в друзья" in social networks. Here the word "friends" is used in the sense of "friend list", not of the humans themselves.

As such, "в гостях" reflects the prepositional usage of в, while "в гости" reflects the accusative usage of a noun which, although derived from the word for "guests", here implies a change in quality/state, rather than the embodiment of the guests themselves.

By the way, remember that лицо is inanimate when meaning "face" and animate as a formal word for "person". Which implies an animate accusative plural in "лиц". Like in the idiom "мера на лиц...", "a measure, concerning [a group of specific] people".

Answer (score -1):

"в гости" (и "в гостях") here is an adverb, not really a noun with a preposition.

A prepositional plural "в гостях" would mean *inside* the guests (some food, maybe?).

Comment: Well, when я в гостях , I'm inside the guests??? I don't think so...

Comment: @Alex.S that's exactly the point! Illustrates the difference between an adverb, and a noun in the prepositional case.

Comment: Downvoting without even bothering to explain ... Tough croud :)
Acceptance issues?

Comment: Why do you believe that "в гостях" is a prepositional phrase but "в гости" is not? Because "гости" is not the usual accusative form?

Comment: @DavidC "в гостях" (in its usual meaning) is not a prepositional phrase either. It just happens to sound like it by coincidence (strictly speaking, it's probably, not a real coincidence, and there are some historical reasons for it, but that's not relevant here), it's an adverb, just like "в гости" is.
If it was a prepositional, it would mean "inside the guests". Like "к вечеру весь пирог оказался в гостях" ("by the evening, the entire pie was inside the guests"). That's the prepositional.

Comment: Ah, OK. You are saying they are both adverbs and so we should not expect to find modern case endings. That is is coherent position. But it is not a satisfying answer.

Comment: @DavidC the goal of the answer is not to be satisfying. It is to be true (which it is).

Comment: If you believe that "в гости" and "в гостях" are not and never where prepositional phrases, you should explain the historical reasons to which you allude. Otherwise, you have not answered the question which was asked.

Comment: @DavidC I did not say they never were. Maybe they were once. That was never the question though. It was about the present, not the past. I am no historian. I do believe I can speak to the current state of the language, but how it came to be is the whole different question altogether.